# X axis divided into 2 parts having same y-axis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

I want graph which shows one main label on x-axis and other two sublabels which shows current date and previous day date of equaly divided into 24 hours. My y-axis is same for that. I dont know what exactly word for division of x axis. if any one knows plz suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Check With `CPTTestApp` project in your `CorePlot_1.0` example.

All you need to do is Create an another x axis for the same graph.

`axisSet.xAxis2 = [(CPTXYAxis *)[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Add the properties which you need to display.Where you can add your custom label.

Finally add all axis into the graph.

`graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:axisSet.xAxis,axisSet.yAxis, axisSet.xAxis2,nil];`